# Converting Objective to Swift Table view not displaying the data in the cells

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, xcode6

I'm still very inexperienced with Swift and am having a problem converting an objective-c based app. 
Most of the app is working ... including changing size and colors of section headers and background color of the cells but I cannot display the content of the cells (a TextView and a switch). 
Any suggestions about fixing this would be appreciated. 
I'm including the code where I change the background color which is where I suspect the problem resides:

```
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView,  cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    //variable type is inferred
    var index = indexPath.row

    NSLog ("index %d",indexPath)

    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CELL") as? UITableViewCell

    if cell == nil {
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Value1, reuseIdentifier: "CELL")
    }

    //we know that cell is not empty now so we use ! to force unwrapping
    var grayishCyan = colorWithHexString("#9bc2c2")
    var grayishRed = colorWithHexString("#ffc2c2")

    if (indexPath.row == 0 || indexPath.row%2 == 0) {
        cell!.backgroundColor = grayishCyan;
    }
    else {
        cell!.backgroundColor = grayishRed
    }

    return cell!
} // end of cellForRowAtIndexPath
```

Comment: You can't simply post a snippet of code involved in a larger problem and expect an answer.  You need to troubleshoot it as you would in Obj-C, checking first to see if any of the delegate calls are being made.  If you are using storyboards, you might have missed updating the class name.  From your post though, one could only offer a wild guess.

Comment: I posted the snippet so as not to post too much. I basically converted the objective-c code and as I said everything else functions EXCEPT I should have commented that the dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier method returns nil. Thanks.

Comment: Nothing in your code puts any content into the cell. All it does it change the background colour.   Are you using a custom UITableViewCell subclass?  Is it set in your storyboard or registered somewhere?

Comment: I am using a custom class (nothing else) - I agree that I only changed the background color - but it is not clear where I ought to add the content. All of the examples I have found only seem to apply to UILabels. (In case you haven't already figured this out I am an amateur hacker with little experience with objective-c and swift).

Comment: I've added the full script to http://crewtoronto.ca/sample-code-stackoverflow

Comment: You need to create a UITableViewCell subclass that includes your required UI items - there are lots of tutorials around. Also you need more sophisticated data model than individuals boo leans. I would suggest a dictionary where the key is the item

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I did test a uitableviewcell class but since the objective-c version didn't need it I did not continue with it. Regarding the data model, I am not sure I understand what you mean. The data model has three entities each of them has a key ... the switch entity has the key of switchname and the attributes of switchdescription, and the boolean of switchvalue.

Comment: I made a mistake in describing the data model ... there are 2 entities involved in this view: View which has a key of viewName and attribute of viewDescription; and Switch which has a key of viewName and switchName and attributes switchDescription and switchValue which is a boolean. What do you mean by a dictionary?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I removed the cellForRowAtIndexPath function and replaced it with the willDisplayCell function